# Oracle select MAX from duplicated data

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates

I need to select ONLY ONE RECORD with 'DOC_NO', but the result is DUPLICATED.

```
SELECT DOC_NO
       , (SELECT MAX(SUBJECT) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY vsize(SUBJECT) DESC)
           FROM MainData MD2 
          WHERE MD.DOC_NO = MD2.DOC_NO) AS SUB
       , count(*)
  FROM MainData MD
  WHERE 1=1                   
  GROUP BY DOC_NO, SUBJECT
  ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

→ I expected the result count would be all 1. But in the result, some are 2, 3..

Original data is below

```
(...) DOC_NO      SUB
      111a        'the example'
      111a        'the example'
      111a        'the example'
      222a        'the example2'    
      222a        'the example2'      
      333a        'the example3'       
      333a        'the example3'
```

→ both (DOC_NO, SUB) are not PK. So the duplication is allowed.

PLEASE let me know how to select one record among the duplication.

add & edit >>

I expected the result as

```
DOC_RNO    SUB             count(*) 
111a     'the example'     1   
222a     'the example2'    1 
333a     'the example3'    1
```

However, the reult is

```
DOC_RNO    SUB             count(*) 
111a     'the example'     3    
222a     'the example2'    2 
333a     'the example3'    2
```

Comment: Give some rows of sample data with necessary columns and your expected output based on that

Comment: Without you sample data, which gives you this output, it is difficult to give you any answer

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I edited.

Comment: WHEre is the SUBJECT column in the GROUP BY?Don`t you mean SUB?

Comment: Do you just want to hardcode 1 for every `docNo` and `sub` combination? If yes then just use `select DOC_RNO, SUB,  1 as count1 from your table group by DOC_RNO, SUB`

Comment: Mihai // As I know, putting a field to group by clause wihout conditions is enough. Is this wrong? Actually the result is same even though I put the condition on where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as

```
SELECT doc_no, sub, COUNT (*)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT doc_no, sub FROM maindata)
GROUP BY doc_no, sub
ORDER BY doc_no;
```

Not sure why you have sub-query to get the subject with dense rank, if you insist on having with sub-query, you can try as

```
  SELECT doc_no, sub, COUNT (*)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                 doc_no,
                 (SELECT MAX (sub)
                            KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY VSIZE (sub) DESC)
                    FROM test_data md2
                   WHERE md.doc_no = md2.doc_no)
                    sub
            FROM test_data md)
GROUP BY doc_no, sub
ORDER BY doc_no;
```

[Demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E1Z4ZUIPYU2U6WT0SM7ICRQ9S.html)

Comment: Thx! With your answer, I could review what I've misunderstood.

Comment: @kdragon First, take the distinct of the rows in the subquery and use the count function in the outer query to get the unique count of doc_no. Glad that I could be of some help.